# Javascript form validation part to check the empty data field is not working

Tags: javascript, html

This is my login form saved as n_form.html. I am trying to check empty fields but whenever I click login without filling the fields my form redirects to the next page instead of giving a message. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Registration Form Of Teknack</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css-page.css" />
  <script language="Javascript">
      function validateForm(){
         var x=document.forms["n_form"]["Username"].value;
         var y=document.forms["n_form"]["Password"].value;
         if (x==null || x=="" & y==null || y==" "){
               alert("Form must be filled.");
               return false;
         }
     }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <br><br><br>
     <form name="n_form" action="form.php"  onclick="return validateForm()"        method="post">      
     <ol>
        <li>Username<br> 
            <input id="width" type="text" name="name" value="" /></li>
    <li><br>Password<br>
        <input id="width" type="password" name="password" value="" /></li>
        <li><br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Remember me<br></li>
        <li id="login">
        <br><button type="submit">Login</button></li>
     </ol>
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why you are not using `jQuery()`? And why you have 2 same "width" DIV?

Comment: width is the id name from my css code...and am new to javascript so dont know exactly what u mean by jquery??!

Comment: Instead of width into "ID" use "CLASS" into a form. For example `class="width"`. A DIV in form use for jQuery grab data or Javascript for getting a value by using `getElementById()`.

Comment: my css code part -      form #width   { width:300px;    }. without this my remember me button is been positioned wrongly.!

Comment: Change to `.width { width:300px; }.` and in in HTML code to `class="width"`

Comment: do you require me to use class selector instead of id? and could u plz explain the getelementById() part ? i really dint get the link between the two ! i did the changes..but my validation part is not working.

Comment: got the solution...var x=document.forms["n_form"]["name"].value; var y=document.forms["n_form"]["password"].value;     instead of username i had to write name...:) thanks for being there..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.n_form.name.value;
var y=document.n_form.password.value;
 if (x==null || x=="" && y==null || y=="")
 {
alert("Form must be filled.");
return false;
  }
 }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zqJkv/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend to use jQuery instead Javascript! Get and learn. However this is answer:

Tutorial demos of jQuery validations and forms: http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/17/10-useful-jquery-form-validation-techniques-and-tutorials-2/

A solution in Javascript:

Javascript code:

```
<script language="javascript">
function validateForm(form)
{
 var username=getElementbyId('username').value;
 var password=getElementbyId('password').value;
 if(username == "")
 {
   alert("You must fill up username!");
 }
 else if (password == "")
 {
   alert("You must fill up password!");
 }
 else
 {
   // nothing, okay status...
 }

     // or if you want to show a message on one of empty field:

 if (username == "" || password == "")
 {
   alert("You must fill up a form");
 }
 else
 {
   // nothing, okay status...
 }


}
```

And change in a HTML FORM:

```
<li>Username<br>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="" />
</li>


<li><br>Password<br>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" value="" />
</li>

<li><br><input type="checkbox" value="">Remember me<br>
</li>


<li id="login">
    <br><button type="button" onclick="check(this.form)">Login</button>
</li>
```

Comment: thank you. and i wil surely learn jquery to make efficient webpages :)